# Using cabal with multiple GHC versions

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I got both ghc6 and ghc7 on my desktop. To install new packages (for the specific ghc version), I use `cabal` with the flag `--with-compiler=<ghc-dir>` to specify for which ghc i want the package installed.

I do `cabal update` before installing any new package. But how to I specify for which ghc I want the update? I mean, there is no `--with-compiler` flag as with `cabal install`. I would think that just like I use `ghc-pkg7` for ghc7, there would be `cabal7`. Apart from the `cabal install` command which I know to which ghc version it is applying, I don't know which ghc is affected with the other cabal commands.

Also, when I do `ghc-pkg check` I find problems with some packages and I don't know how to fix.

I would really like to know - if anyone does have - good practices when using multiple ghc versions on the same machine. e.g. how to proceed with installation, updates, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create two configuration files, say `~/.cabal/config` and `~/.cabal/config7`, and use the un(der)documented option `--config-file` to select between the two.

Comment: this seemed to be an option but when i looked in the `config` file, it does not specify which ghc to use.

Comment: In my `~/.cabal/config` there is a commented-out option `with-compiler`. I suppose one should uncomment it.

Comment: It seems like `--config-file` is an option, though i could not find more about it. I don't expect to get any other answer, may be there isn't. I don't see the point why most of the folks out there will have different versions :) in my case, i needed old+new ghc to be able to work with some old packages/extensions..

Answer (score 8):

I thought `--with-ghc` is the appropriate option.
I use to have multiple `ghc` versions on my machine. They all have different names like `ghc-6.12.3` or `ghc-7.4.1`. They are usually installed with these names and a default compiler is chosen by creating symbolic links from, say, `ghc` to `ghc-7.4.1`.
I think you do not need different cabal directories for different `ghc` versions. Cabal creates a `ghc-6.12.3` subdirectory of `lib/yourpkg` for `GHC-6.12.3` files and so on.
Also `cabal update` does not update installed packages, it only fetches the current package list from your favorite package servers. This should be the same for all installed compilers.

Answer (score 7):

`cabal update` has no `--with-compiler` option because it is completely compiler-agnostic -- it doesn't involve GHC or any other compiler at all. It just downloads a list of available packages from Hackage, nothing more. You can expect that something similar applies to other commands which do not let you choose a compiler (as the dev team was careful to avoid making cabal GHC-specific, let alone specific to a particular GHC version, wherever that makes sense).

Answer (score 5):

This answer serves to complement the other answers
(that are already enlightening).

First of all, know
that there are significant differences
between minor versions of GHC.
For example, the change
from GHC 7.8 to GHC 7.10
(cf. [burning bridges proposal](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9586)).
So, it might be better
to name your GHC binaries
also including minor version numbers, like:
`ghc7.8` and `ghc7.10`.

Supposing you have several GHCs installed with the following names:

```
/usr/bin/ghc
/usr/bin/ghc-pkg
/usr/bin/haddock
...
/usr/bin/ghc-7.8
/usr/bin/ghc-pkg-7.8
/usr/bin/haddock-ghc-7.8
...
/usr/bin/ghc-7.6
/usr/bin/ghc-pkg-7.6
/usr/bin/haddock-ghc-7.6
...
(and so on)
```

For GHC 7.8,
you can create a file called `~/.cabal-ghc-7.8/config`
with the following contents
(that point to the locations described above):

```
remote-repo: hackage.haskell.org:http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive
remote-repo-cache: /home/<USER>/.cabal-ghc-7.8/packages
world-file:        /home/<USER>/.cabal-ghc-7.8/world
compiler: ghc
extra-prog-path:   /home/<USER>/.cabal-ghc-7.8/bin
build-summary:     /home/<USER>/.cabal-ghc-7.8/logs/build.log
remote-build-reporting: anonymous
jobs: $ncpus

install-dirs user
  prefix:          /home/<USER>/.cabal-ghc-7.8

program-locations
  ghc-location:     /usr/bin/ghc-7.8
  ghc-pkg-location: /usr/bin/ghc-pkg-7.8
  haddock-location: /usr/bin/haddock-ghc-7.8
  hpc-location:     /usr/bin/hpc-ghc-7.8
  hsc2hs-location:  /usr/bin/hsc2hs-ghc-7.8
```

You can create an executable
possibly called `cabal-ghc-7.8` in your `PATH`
(it uses the `--config-file` option [described in n.m.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7806877)):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
exec cabal --config-file=$HOME/.cabal-ghc-7.8/config "$@"
```

Now, in your cabalized source dir,
you can simply run `cabal-ghc-7.8 build`
to build your source files using GHC 7.8.
(or `cabal-ghc-7.8 test` or anything else)

You can repeat the process for all the GHCs you have installed.
Of course, you should not worry about the standard named GHC.
By default, Cabal searches for a GHC named `ghc`.

This answer assumes a UNIX/Linux system (like the use of `bash`), but can be adapted to other systems with small changes.

Answer (score 1):

Now (cabal version 1.24.0.0), one can

```
$ cabal install <package name> -w path-to-ghc-executable-1 
$ cabal install <package name> -w path-to-ghc-executable-2
```

to install packages separately for multiple different GHCs.

(The meta-variable `path-to-ghc-executable-i` can be, like, `/usr/bin/ghc-7.10.3`, `/usr/local/bin/ghc-8.4.3` etc.)

How did I know? This command can be found via https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html or `cabal install --help`.

The post-condition looks like this: I installed `QuickCheck` for `ghc-8.0.1` and `ghc-6.12.1`, then `~/.cabal/lib` looks like:

```
➜  lib pwd      
/home/lee/.cabal/lib
➜  lib tree -L 2
.
├── x86_64-linux-ghc-6.12.1
│   └── QuickCheck-2.8.2-GeOZQRSfeF7EtuZhBovRUq
└── x86_64-linux-ghc-8.0.1
    └── QuickCheck-2.9.2-AzbjWrJo3WFD60ZxKurQ3s
```