# Can't install Grapefruit on Windows 10

Tags: haskell, cabal

When running cabal install grapefruit-ui-gtk I get build errors on the dependency TypeCompose. The exact command I run is

```
cabal install grapefruit-ui-gtk
```

and get the following error output:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring TypeCompose-0.9.12...
Configuring hashtables-1.2.3.1...
Building TypeCompose-0.9.12...
Building hashtables-1.2.3.1...
Failed to install TypeCompose-0.9.12
Build log ( C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\ghc-8.4.3\TypeCompose-0.9.12-4FepCXFvbF94E2D2EggnNC.log ):
Preprocessing library for TypeCompose-0.9.12..
Building library for TypeCompose-0.9.12..
src\Data\Title.hs:1:33: warning:
    -XOverlappingInstances is deprecated: instead use per-instance pragmas OVERLAPPING/OVERLAPPABLE/OVERLAPS
  |
1 | {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances, TypeOperators, TypeSynonymInstances #-}
  |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ 1 of 10] Compiling Control.Instances ( src\Control\Instances.hs, dist\build\Control\Instances.o )
[ 2 of 10] Compiling Data.Bijection   ( src\Data\Bijection.hs, dist\build\Data\Bijection.o )
[ 3 of 10] Compiling Control.Compose  ( src\Control\Compose.hs, dist\build\Control\Compose.o )
src\Control\Compose.hs:596:10: error:
    * Could not deduce (Semigroup (Flip j o a))
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      from the context: (Applicative (j a), Monoid o)
        bound by the instance declaration
        at src\Control\Compose.hs:596:10-61
    * In the instance declaration for `Monoid (Flip j o a)'
    |
596 | instance (Applicative (j a), Monoid o) => Monoid (Flip j o a) where
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
src\Control\Compose.hs:645:10: error:
    * Could not deduce (Semigroup (App f m))
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      from the context: (Applicative f, Monoid m)
        bound by the instance declaration
        at src\Control\Compose.hs:645:10-54
    * In the instance declaration for `Monoid (App f m)'
    |
645 | instance (Applicative f, Monoid m) => Monoid (App f m) where
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
src\Control\Compose.hs:851:1: error:
    * Could not deduce (Semigroup (Arrw j f g a))
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      from the context: Monoid (j (f a) (g a))
        bound by the instance declaration
        at src\Control\Compose.hs:851:1-63
    * In the instance declaration for `Monoid (Arrw j f g a)'
    |
851 | deriving instance Monoid (f a `j` g a) => Monoid (Arrw j f g a)
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cabal: Leaving directory 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-17748\TypeCompose-0.9.12'
Installed hashtables-1.2.3.1
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
TypeCompose-0.9.12-4FepCXFvbF94E2D2EggnNC failed during the building phase.
The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
grapefruit-frp-0.1.0.7-28vOfRvsiGH71mjsrgG35Q depends on
grapefruit-frp-0.1.0.7 which failed to install.
grapefruit-records-0.1.0.7-Ih2DxRIbFnG7TB7BHtPbwq depends on
grapefruit-records-0.1.0.7 which failed to install.
grapefruit-ui-0.1.0.7-DMol4wZpyyFEHFP2NRKthr depends on grapefruit-ui-0.1.0.7
which failed to install.
grapefruit-ui-gtk-0.1.0.7-EsNz0f5KGlp47W2BX85WRG depends on
grapefruit-ui-gtk-0.1.0.7 which failed to install.
```

GHC Version:

> The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.4.3

Cabal version:

> cabal-install version 2.2.0.0 compiled using version 2.2.0.1 of the
>   Cabal library

What could be causing this issue? I have tried installing it in a fresh directory with cabal init, and that didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: It looks like the dependency bounds on the problematic version of `TypeCompose` have been fixed: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose-0.9.12/revisions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/conal/TypeCompose/issues/6) with TypeCompose under 8.4, which [has been fixed](https://github.com/conal/TypeCompose/pull/7) but not put on Hackage yet.

You might be able to configure your `cabal` commands with an older version of GHC (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770100/using-cabal-with-multiple-ghc-versions)), such as 8.2.2, which shouldn't have this issue.

Alternatively, use `stack`, which will let you switch ghc versions per-project, and which provides TypeCompose for 8.2.2 on the [LTS resolver](https://www.stackage.org/lts-11.22/package/TypeCompose-0.9.12).

Comment: I have done this, and now I'm getting an entirely *different* error:

src\Graphics\UI\Grapefruit\GTK.hs:182:67: error:
        * Couldn't match expected type `Maybe model0'
                      with actual type `Gtk.ListStore el'

Comment: Apparently the 8.4.3 compatible version has been released to Hackage - have you had any luck trying to install it again with that GHC version?