# Can older Cabal or Haskell projects be run on newer versions of Cabal and Haskell?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to build my project and I'm running into a really strange problem. I got my friend to install Haskell with Chocolatey and when he goes to compile my project with `cabal build` and `cabal run project` he runs into the following error that I just don't have:

```
Expr.hs:103:1: error:
    Type applications in patterns are not yet supported
    |
103 | evalVal env val @(HInteger _)      = return $ val
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I assumed that the cabal file would take care of dependencies but obviously not. A cursory search as well proves fruitless because I can't even find another instance of someone having the same error.

I'm not sure if the problem is due to him being on `ghc 9.0.1` and `cabal 3.4` and I'm on `ghc 8.8.3` and `cabal 3.2` or if it's due to different operating systems, his being Windows and I OSX.

My worry is that if I upgrade my ghc and cabal versions then I will run into this error and I'll have to reinstall everything which was messy and difficult the first time

Comment: I doubt it's cabal but different GHC-versions are usually a problem - I would recommend something like GHCUP to switch versions on demand (or stack) - it's only a hunch but does it go away if your remove the space between `val` and `@(HInteger_ )`?

Comment: maybe this can help you out too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770100/using-cabal-with-multiple-ghc-versions

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at GHCUP and the link! Hopefully that's all there is to it

Comment: please try `val@(HInteger _)` too - it's only a wild guess but maybe they changed syntax there so that as-patterns are without-space and the space indicates the type-application (as the error hints at) - I am a bit excited that it says (not supported **yet**) as I could see some use cases for that - but that is another matter

Comment: You won't believe it...changing it to `val@(HInteger _)` actually worked. The other thing that had to be done was to install System.Random and then it just worked...thank you so much

Comment: I belive it and I found out why: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/migration/9.0#whitespace-sensitive-and-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that was a change in GHC 9.0: [Whitespace-sensitive !, ~, @, and $](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/migration/9.0#whitespace-sensitive-and-)

it's the second point there:

> f @ x = y
>
> Before: value binding that binds both f and x to y using an as-pattern
> After: infix function named (@)
>
> To restore the old behavior, remove the leading and trailing whitespace around @, like so:
>
> f@x = x

So if you change it to

```
evalVal env val@(HInteger _)      = return $ val
```

it should work for both compilers